# Add <span> elements after <img> elements within parent ID

Tags: javascript, magento-1.9, appendchild, getelementsbytagname

I'm struggling to make a JS code that will add a `<span>` element after each `<img>` tag within a certain parrent.

This is the HTML structure (shortened version):

```
<ul id="payment_form_quickpaypayment_payment">
    <li>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="qpayment_type" value="dankort" checked="checked">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="/dankort.png" title="Dankort">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="qpayment_type" value="mastercard">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="/mastercard.png" title="MasterCard">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="qpayment_type" value="mastercard-debet">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="/mastercarddebet.png" title="MasterCard Debet DK">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a `<span>` element after each `<img>` element and the content in the `<span>` element should be the text in the `title` attribute of each `<img>`

So the section:

```
<td>
    <img src="/dankort.png" title="Dankort">
</td>
```

should look like this after running the script:

```
<td>
    <img src="/dankort.png" title="Dankort">
    <span>Dankort</span>
</td>
```

This is what I've tried but it's not working:

```
<script>
    function payLoad() {
        var selectedImage = document.getElementById("payment_form_quickpaypayment_payment").getElementsByTagName('img');

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < selectedImage.length; i++) {
            var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
            var currentImgTitle = selectedImage[i].title();
            var t = document.createTextNode(currentImgTitle);
            newSpan.appendChild(t);
            selectedImage[i].appendChild(newSpan);
        }
    }
    window.onload = payLoad;
</script>
```

Comment: What is not working ? What is the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do `.title()` it's not a function but a property of the `img`.

```html
<ul id="payment_form_quickpaypayment_payment">
  <li>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" class="radio" name="qpayment_type" value="dankort" checked="checked">
          </td>
          <td>
            <img src="/dankort.png" title="Dankort">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" class="radio" name="qpayment_type" value="mastercard">
          </td>
          <td>
            <img src="/mastercard.png" title="MasterCard">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" class="radio" name="qpayment_type" value="mastercard-debet">
          </td>
          <td>
            <img src="/mastercarddebet.png" title="MasterCard Debet DK">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </li>
</ul>
<script>
  function payLoad() {
    var selectedImage = document.getElementById("payment_form_quickpaypayment_payment").getElementsByTagName('img');

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < selectedImage.length; i++) {
      var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
      newSpan.innerText = selectedImage[i].title
      selectedImage[i].parentNode.appendChild(newSpan);
    }
  }
  window.onload = payLoad;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. The code snippet works great but I get this error when adding the script to the page: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null at payLoad`

Comment: You need to be sure that your id is right. You can add a test to see if  `document.getElementById("payment_form_quickpaypayment_payment")` doesn't return `null`.

Comment: Thanks. Your code works great. The id was right but the "payment" section isn't loaded on "page load" but only when you get to the payment section in the Magento One Page checkout. I'll just have to find a way to load this script when this section loads.

Answer (score 0):

`selectedImage[i].appendChild(newSpan);` will add `span` into `img` as its child, if you want to make them siblings, you need `selectedImage[i].parentNode.appendChild(newSpan);`.

Tips: you can use browser inspector to view html hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

Your way of getting title attr is wrong. Need to do

```
 var currentImgTitle = selectedImage[i].title;
```

I have implemented  like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    payLoad();
});
function payLoad() {
    var selectedImage = document.getElementById("payment_form_quickpaypayment_payment").getElementsByTagName('img');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < selectedImage.length; i++)      {
    var newSpan =   document.createElement("span");
            var currentImgTitle = selectedImage[i].title;

            var t = document.createTextNode(currentImgTitle);
            newSpan.appendChild(t);
            selectedImage[i].appendChild(newSpan);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But i get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null`

Comment: I know you have already got the solution but I am not getting any such error you mentioned. Here is the JsFiddle link you can look at if you like.
(https://jsfiddle.net/r6qpqt5v/)

Comment: Yes, your code also works great (if I change the `$` to `jQuery` since I'm also running prototype.js). I was getting this error because the parrent with the ID used in the script doesn't load on "page load" but is injected later with JS.